# Question about linear non-autonomous ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently learning about ode's and I am on the topic of linear non-autonomous ode's. The professor is deriving the solution to the following ode using *some* integrating factor $I$.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t)x+B(t)$$

So these are the steps that he makes in finding $x$.

$$\begin{align}
I\left(\frac{dx}{dt} - Ax = B \right) \\
I\frac{dx}{dt} - AIx = IB \\
I\frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{dI}{dt} x = IB \\
d(Ix) = IB \\
\frac{dI}{dt} = -AI
\end{align}$$

I understand all of those steps and now, since this a simple ode we can separate it and arrive at solution for $I$ as

$$I = \exp (\int -Adt) = e^{-\int A}$$

Now, takes this solution of $I$ and uses it in $d(Ix) = IB$ by integrating both sides and subbing in $I$.

$$\begin{align}
Ix &= \int IB \\
x &= \frac{1}{I} \int IB \\
x &= e^{\int A} (\int B e^{-\int A}) & \text{?!} \\
\end{align}$$

That last bit is where my confusion is. How did he arrive at the last step because if we sub in $I$, should it not be $\frac{1}{e^{-\int A}}$? Where did the negative go and why is it reciprocal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were he, I would write $I=e^{-\int A}+C$ instead, but if we're assumed to have $C=0$ then $I=e^{-\int A}$ is the correct one. Now, if $Ix=\int IB$, with the substitution $I=e^{-\int A}$, we certainly get his last solution. Note that $\frac{1}I=\frac{1}{e^{-\int A}}=e^{\int A}$.

Comment: Oh I get it now! I see where my mistake was.

Comment: (+1) nice answer. By the way the [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456246/proof-int-infty-infty-deltat2-dt-1/456251) you upvoted is correct. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion arises from that fact that I was thinking that $\frac{1}{e^{-\int A}}$ was different from $\frac{1}{e^{-x}}$ but that is not the case. The negative sign in front of the $x$ is what reciprocates it into $e^{\int A}$.

Comment: I think he is right. Indeed, $1/x^a=x^{-a}$ and vice vers